# Nextjs: show not-found page when handle in middleware using app dir

Tags: next.js, next-router, custom-error-pages

I have a `nextjs` using `app` dir.

The app suport multi language: `/[lang]/<router>`.

The `[lang]` is reqiured for all route and only have some language.

I want to validate the `[lang]` is correct. If not, show `not-found.tsx`.

The `app` support `not-found.tsx` so I dont want to create an `404/page.txs` or `_404/page.tsx` or some thing similer.

I want to handle in `middleware.ts`.

Ex: I support 2 language : `en` and `vi`. The route shold be `/en/<route>` or `/vi/<route>`.

If user access to some thing like `/abc` or `/xyz/foobar`, `not-found.tsx` sould be display.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hey! Since it's your second post in 2 hours regarding this matter, I recommend you go through one of the guides on how to implement i18n support, for example https://locize.com/blog/next-13-app-dir-i18n/
Particularly regarding middleware - that's what this question is about.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the App dir you can very easily handle this in the layout.tsx inside of your [lang] folder. Simply do something like this:

```js
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';


export default function Layout({
    children,
    params,
}: {
    children: ReactNode;
    params: { lang: string };
}): JSX.Element {
    const langValid = ['es', 'vi'].includes(params.lang);
    
    if (!langValid) {
      return notFound();
    }
    
    return <>
      // Whatever your layout looks like
      {children}
    </>;

}
```

For more info on this, checkout the docs here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization

Comment: thanks for ur ans. But I got this: `Application error: a server-side exception has occurred (see the server logs for more information).
Digest: NEXT_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: I checked terminal and no log. (The root layout is `use client`).
my code:: 

`if (!language.some((item) => item.key === params.lang)) {
    console.log('not found')

    return notFound()
  }`